# How to implement custom interfaces in WPF UserControl and avoid dynamic casts?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have several WPF UserControls. Each of these controls implement an interface `IStepEditor`

The class declaration is as follow:

```
 public partial class EditorLoadCsv : UserControl, IStepEditor { ... }
```

`IStepEditor` is not very important, but it is currently defined as follow:

```
public interface IStepEditor
{
    StepConfig Save();
    void Load(StepConfig config);
}
```

I then have several classes holding those controls, like this:

```
public class StepConfigController
{
    public IStepEditor EditorControl { get; }
}
```

All of this is working as expected when I use `IStepEditor` all around, but to add those controls to a WPF window from a StepConfigController, I eventually have to cast them in a `UserControl`, like this:

```
((StackPanel)panEditorControl).Children.Add(currentControl as UserControl);
```

Since the IStepEditor implementation is actually a UserControl, it works. I could add checks for that cast, but the whole idea seems wrong. I cast an object to another very unrelated object through some weak relationship I trust others to follow.

I tried to create an abstract class inheriting from both `UserControl` and `IStepEditor` and have my actual `UserControl`s derive from that, but since the WPF `UserControl`s are `partial classes`, it didn't work. It was something like this:

```
public abstract class StepEditorControl : UserControl, IStepEditor
{
    abstract public StepConfig Save();
    abstract public Load(StepConfig config);
}
```

So this class was legit and compiled, but trying to derive from it in WPF failed.

```
public partial class EditorLoadCsv : StepEditorControl
{
}
```

This code generates:

```
error CS0263: Partial declarations of 'EditorLoadCsv' must not specify different base classes
```

Which is right, because the xaml markup still references a `UserControl`. Trying to change the xaml markups from `UserControl` to a `StepEditorControl` failed, but it could be the proper solution to the whole problem. I also tried to implement a WPF Custom Control Library, but it seemed like a lot of work just to implement an interface with 2 methods.

The XAML is generated automagically through Visual Studio designer:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.EditorLoadCsv"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="623.077">

<!--- Actual UserControl content ---!>

</UserControl>
```

So an answer to either of these questions could solve my problem:

1- How to avoid a (possibly) dangerous dynamic cast when implementing WPF UserControl with custom interfaces?
2- How to get WPF XAML markup to accept a custom class instead of UserControl?
3- How to refactor code to avoid this ugliness in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Panel.Children` property is a UIElementCollection, so anything that should be added needs to be a UIElement, which is the base class of all WPF UI components.

Do not use the `as` operator, but simply cast your editor objects to UIElement. If any of them is by accident not a UIElement, you would correctly get an `InvalidCastException`.

```
((Panel)panEditorControl).Children.Add((UIElement)currentControl);
```

---

In order to create a UserControl-derived base class for all your StepEditors, you did the first step correctly:

```
public abstract class StepEditorControl : UserControl, IStepEditor
{
    public abstract void Load(StepConfig config);
    public abstract StepConfig Save();
}
```

However, the XAML of a control derived from StepEditorControl would have to look like this:

```
<local:StepEditorControl
    x:Class="MyNamespace.EditorLoadCsv"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    ...>
    ...
</local:StepEditorControl>
```